# Install the latest Lombok on the latest Eclipse on macbook pro mojave

Tags: eclipse, lombok

I am trying to install the latest Lombok -1.18.10.jar on Eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200 on macbook pro Mojave10.14.6.

After invoking Java -jar lombok.jar command on terminal, since it did not identified any eclipse IDE on my system, I get to choose the install location of my Eclipse. From configuration dialog page of Eclipse, I noted my Eclipse launcher is at **/Users/pnutalap/Desktop/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse** . But when I select that location for Lombok, I get a message saying that  "I can't find any IDE that Lombok supports at location /Users/pnutalap/Desktop/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.

Does any incompatibility between Lombok and latest eclipse ?
Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by locating the eclipse.ini file. Using the above installation path, that would be /Users/pnutalap/Desktop/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini